# laravel 5.2 - store multiple value with sum

Tags: laravel, eloquent, records

I have a 2 table user and reports

Report model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'author_id');
}
```

User model

```
public function reports() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Report', 'author_id');
}
```

In User model there is a column called "sum_sales"
In Report model there is a column called "total"

Ho can I pass the sum(total) from my Report model to 'sum_total' inside my User model?
My report controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required',
                             'date' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/',
                             'image_1' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg',
                             'products' => 'required',
                             'total' => 'required',
                             'time' => 'required|min:2',
                             'location' => 'required',
                             'sub_location' => 'required',
                            ]);

  $user = Auth::user()->id;

  $report = new Report($request->all());
  $report->author_id = $user;

  $image = $request->file('image_1');
  $destinationPath = 'uploads/reports';
  $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$ext;

  $report->image_1 = $image->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

  $field_total = $request->input('total');
  $sum_total = $report->sum('total');
  $totalSum = $field_total + $sum_total;

  $report->author_id->sum_sales = $totalSum;    

  $report->save();

  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

  return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```

With this the browser say:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Report::$author_id has no effect
```

How can I figure out?

Comment: Instead of `$report->author_id->sum_sales`, write `$user->sum_sales` and You should be good to go.

Comment: I try, but throw me: **Attempt to assign property of non-object**

Comment: Whoops, didn't noticed that `$user` is just an id. Then write `Auth::user()->update(['sum_sales' => $totalSum])`. Make sure `sum_sales` attribute is in fillable array.

Comment: ohhhh man, it works! thank you so much, i spent my last 2 days inside this limbo, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

solved by Giedrius Kiršys

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $this->validate($request, ['title' => 'required',
                             'date' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|regex:/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/',
                             'image_1' => 'required|mimes:png,jpeg',
                             'products' => 'required',
                             'total' => 'required',
                             'time' => 'required|min:2',
                             'location' => 'required',
                             'sub_location' => 'required',
                            ]);

  $user = Auth::user()->id;

  $report = new Report($request->all());
  $report->author_id = $user;

  $image = $request->file('image_1');
  $destinationPath = 'uploads/reports';
  $ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$ext;

  $report->image_1 = $image->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
  $report->save();

  $sumUserTotal = User::find($user)->reports->sum('total');
  Auth::user()->update(['sum_sales' => $sumUserTotal]);

  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Report added!');

  return redirect('dash/reports');
}
```